# Fragment onActivityResult returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments

In the app I'm developing, the user can define an image on his profile. The first time the app is executed, an intro activity is shown where the user can choose between selecting a photo from the galery or taking a new one with the camera.

This works fine. After the user sets a profile pic, I save it in the app folder and I can use that pic inside the app later.

My app is based on the Navigation Drawer (support) so it is composed by fragments. One of this fragments is for the user's profile where the profile pic is shown. here, the user has te chance to change this pic again. An here is where I'm getting troubles.

To select a new pic, I'm using the same code I used to get the pic in the intro activity, just adapting some things to the fragment (putting getActivity()). But it seems that is not returning the image to the fragment and it's throwing a NPE.

This is how the pic is selectect from gallery in SettingsFragment:

```
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_FRAG);
```

And here is the onActivityResult in SettingsFragment too:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_FRAG:
            if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                /*We get the image URI*/
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                Bitmap srcBmp = null;
                try {
                    srcBmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.e("GET_IMAGE", e.getMessage(), e);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("GET_IMAGE", e.getMessage(), e);
                }

                /*Transform the original image to landscape to use it as profile background*/
                Bitmap landBmp = null;
                if (srcBmp.getWidth() <= srcBmp.getHeight()) {
                    landBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                            srcBmp,
                            0,
                            srcBmp.getHeight()/2 - srcBmp.getWidth()/2, //srcBmp.getHeight()/4 ?
                            srcBmp.getWidth(),
                            srcBmp.getWidth() /2
                    );
                }

                /*Scale the bitmap*/
                int originalWidth = srcBmp.getWidth();
                int originalHeight = srcBmp.getHeight();
                int newWidth = 400;
                int newHeight = (originalHeight*newWidth)/originalWidth;
                Bitmap fullbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(landBmp, newWidth, newHeight, true);
                /*Save the bitmap in app-folder*/
                ContextWrapper cw1 = new ContextWrapper(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                File directory1 = cw1.getDir("profile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                if (!directory1.exists()) {
                    directory1.mkdir();
                }
                File filepath1 = new File(directory1, "profile_pic.png");
                FileOutputStream fos1 = null;
                try {
                    fos1 = new FileOutputStream(filepath1);
                    fullbitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos1);
                    fos1.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("SAVE_FULL_IMAGE", e.getMessage(), e);
                }

                /*Show background profile pic*/
                Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), fullbitmap);
                header_container.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
            }
            break;
```

But as said, the app crashes an this is what logcat tells:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=131073, result=-1, 
    data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/204 flg=0x1 }}   
    to activity {com.myproject.executer/com.myproject.executer.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.NullPointerException at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3389)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:590) 
    at com.myproject.executer.SettingsFragment.onActivityResult(SettingsFragment.java:275)
```

Where line 275 is `Bitmap fullbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(landBmp, newWidth, newHeight, true);`

So, I don't understand well what is happening, because it says something that is failing to deviler the result to MainActivity , and it has to deliver the result to SettingsFragment.

Comment: Check if srcBmp variable is null or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `onActivityResult()` method doesn't complete and return, the system counts it as the delivery having failed, which is why the errors start with that message.

In your code, it would seem that `landBmp` is null, because the condition `srcBmp.getWidth() <= srcBmp.getHeight()` is false, and you don't initialize `landBmp` in that case. This is throwing the `NullPointerException`, and halting execution before `onActivityResult()` returns.

Comment: Thankyou very much Mike! I didn't realize that I haven't that handled! Such a mistake

Answer (score 0):

**you can reading** :http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-fix-nested-fragment-onactivityresult-issue/en?fb_action_ids=780839882030502&fb_action_types=og.comments

Create ActivityResultEvent.java

```
import android.content.Intent;

/**
 * Created by nuuneoi on 3/12/2015.
 */
public class ActivityResultEvent {

    private int requestCode;
    private int resultCode;
    private Intent data;

    public ActivityResultEvent(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        this.requestCode = requestCode;
        this.resultCode = resultCode;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public int getRequestCode() {
        return requestCode;
    }

    public void setRequestCode(int requestCode) {
        this.requestCode = requestCode;
    }

    public int getResultCode() {
        return resultCode;
    }

    public void setResultCode(int resultCode) {
        this.resultCode = resultCode;
    }

    public Intent getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Intent data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Create ActivityResultBus.java

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;

import com.squareup.otto.Bus;

/**
 * Created by nuuneoi on 3/12/2015.
 */
public class ActivityResultBus extends Bus {

    private static ActivityResultBus instance;

    public static ActivityResultBus getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new ActivityResultBus();
        return instance;
    }

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    public void postQueue(final Object obj) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ActivityResultBus.getInstance().post(obj);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

// >>>>>>>>>>>>>> **override onActivityResult on Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        ActivityResultBus.getInstance().postQueue(
                    new ActivityResultEvent(requestCode, resultCode, data));
    }

    ...

}
```

**In fragment :**

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // Don't forget to check requestCode before continuing your job
        if (requestCode == 12345) {
            // Do your job
            tvResult.setText("Result Code = " + resultCode);
        }
    }
 @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        ActivityResultBus.getInstance().register(mActivityResultSubscriber);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        ActivityResultBus.getInstance().unregister(mActivityResultSubscriber);
    }

    private Object mActivityResultSubscriber = new Object() {
        @Subscribe
        public void onActivityResultReceived(ActivityResultEvent event) {
            int requestCode = event.getRequestCode();
            int resultCode = event.getResultCode();
            Intent data = event.getData();
            onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    };
```